# Purple screen in XNA 4.0 when switching screens - backbuffer data disapearing (most likely?)

Tags: .net, xna, screen

I am trying my hand at XNA 4.0 with friends, and we are implementing a Game implying to switch screens, common things like a MainMenu, a GamingScreen, a MultiplayerScreen, etc.

The problem I have is, only on my Windows7 tower, not on any of my friend`s computers, I get a purple screen of death when switching Screens FROM the MainMenu. I'll take going to GamingScreen as an example.

Our Game1 has a currentScreen (ENUM WhichScreen) attribute. It starts with the MainMenu, and at each Draw and each Update, we switch on the currentScreen to choose which screen to call Draw and Update on. So as `Game1.Update` and `Game1.Draw` alternate, it might go in order as follows:

```
MainMenuScreen.Draw
MainMenuScreen.Update
GamingScreen.Draw
GamingScreen.Update
GamingScreen.Draw
```

In MainMenuScreen`s update, its components (homemade class) are updated, and it happens that`Game1.currentScreen` is changed from MainMenu to Gaming.

But for some reason, upon `Draw()`, most precisely in `EndDraw()`  (to my understanding,  `GraphicsDevice.Present`), the screen becomes purple.

I have tried tons of way to debug and have parsed these forums, but to no avail. Suspending a Draw (waiting for GamingScreen to Update, for instance) does not suffice, as the screen will become purple again.

Important note: I have set it so that MainMenuScreen Draws AND GamingScreen Updates before GameingScreen dars. What happened was quite peculiar: It's MainMenu`s Draw that caused the purple screen!

So that point I am at is: somewhere from the clikcing part in the Update to the `EndDraw()`, at one point, the backbuffer screws itself for no apparent reason, before GamingScreen EVEN ENTERS INTO ANY ACTION WHATSOEVER.

Upon the screen becoming purple, I checked and detected that `this.UponDeactivate()` is called. However calling a `this.UponActivate()` did not help me.

After the pruple screen is there:
-The updates are still succesfully called on Game1 -> GamingScreen, and even going over the buttons hidden under the purple works (I get button hovering sounds)
-The Draws are also called, but not with success, as the screen stays purple. 
-Minimizing the window and re-opening it REMOVES THE PURPLE AND MAKES IT WORK. This sounds quite important, this is what led me to call `this.UponActivate()`.

To make a summary, I have no clue what causes the back buffer to go mad with being empty. It has to be something changed by clicking the button, but the wierd part is how only clicking already screwed the screen.

It would be hard to give you all the code called between the classes in the important parts. After changeGameState, the button finishes his execute(), then its panel finishes its update, then the big panel itself updates one other panel. Then, we are back in Game1's code, which simply finishes `Update()` with `base.Update()` (I also tried putting `base.Update()` to the top of Update, to no avail), and then moves on to BeginDraw. A bit later, `EndDraw()` empties the screen.

Is it important the order (first of Draw or laft of Draw, first of Update or last of `Update()` ) in which base.Update is called?
--> What can cause the backbuffer to go crazy like this? Oh god, can calls be made to `Draw()` before and `Update()` is finished? or other `Update()`s?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

**The purple screen indicates an uninitialised buffer.**

Calling `SetRenderTarget` (including with `null`, the backbuffer target) will clear the target that you set to that purple colour, unless that target has `RenderTargetUsage.PreserveContents` set on it (which has performance implications).

Generally you want to set up your rendering so that render targets are rendered first, then the backbuffer. Never swapping back to a buffer you've previously drawn to.

The back and front buffers are also both purple to begin with. So, even if you aren't using render targets, you will see this if you swap a buffer to the front (with `Present`, from `EndDraw`) without actually drawing on it.

Comment: SO then how would I solve my problem? I don't (yet) use Renderers, and I would not know when to apply them to solve my problem. DO you mean I should use setRenderTarget(null) everytime my buffer is empty like this?

Comment: I'm afraid the info provided in your question is insufficient to narrow down where your problem is (you tell us about the functions you call - but they're *your* functions - I have no idea what they do!). So I've given you the only two reasonable ways in which the purple screen can occur in XNA. If you (or any third-party libraries) never call `SetRenderTarget`, then it is likely you're either not drawing to the back buffer, or not flipping the back buffer to the front (for example: by overriding `Game.EndDraw` but not having it call `base.EndDraw()`). The problem is somewhere in your code.